# What are the correct steps to set up the TDengine cluster?

Tags: database, tdengine

I need to build a cluster with one master node and three worker nodes using TDengine. I followed all the step from the official website (https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/cluster), but I still suffered by the offlines from the "show dnodes" command in the taos shell. I think it somehow connected but still miss something. I can use the taos shell to see the cluster status in all worker nodes but just cannot start other slave dnodes. What I did was

- clean up all the previous data
- use the "create dnode xxx" command in taos shell
- modify the FirstEP to the master node for all the taos.cfg in worker nodes
- add the internal ip and hostname to each nodes' /etc/hosts
- start all the taosd services in all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

you should start all taosd services in all nodes first, then use "create dnode xxx" command in taos shell